# Static HTML: iframe tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Is it possible to add more than one instances of Static HTML: iframe tabs in one Facebook Page?

Can someone provide an example?

Comment: its an interesting concept; what are you planning to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you can.  You'll have to open another application and point it to a different folder on your server. You'll have to structure your system to manage multiple facebook apps as one - many app_ids being synchronized - at least on your side.

Answer (score 2):

You can make more than one, just use these links and only up to 12:

1. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/
2. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_two/
3. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_three/
4. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_four/
5. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_five/
6. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_six/
7. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_seven/
8. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_eight/
9. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_nine/
10. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_ten/
11. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_eleven/
12. https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_twelve/

Answer (score 1):

You can add more than one tab with the Static HTML: iframe tabs app. Once you install the app and create a page and save it, you can then go into edit mode on the first page. On the page where you've added your html code for that first tab, look near the top of the page, just below the title of your Fan Page, and you'll see a tab that says "FAQ & Help Center [x]". Click on that tab and it will expand. Next, click on the menu item titled "How do I add more than one tab?". From there select whether it's your second, third, fourth, etc. tab. At this time (January 27, 2012) it appears you can have up to 12 tabs).

Cheers.